# how to take the value of an input and plus it by any number in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

this my code and I can't seem to find out why it returns NaN.
I tried just given it a certain number in the addnum function but that also didn't work.

```
 <script>
     var output = document.getElementById("output");
     var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
     var int_input = parseInt(input);

    function addnum(N) {
        int_input = int_input + N;
        output.innerHTML = int_input;
    }

    document.getElementById("addinput").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            addnum(6);
        }
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: Need to confirm that you have HTML that matches the JavaScript... refer to this section on [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne I made sure that the Html was correct and double checked with the source you suggested. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the JS. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Suit yourself. As far as I can tell the JS is syntactically correct which led me to believe the HTML doesn't gist. Although there's a possible codesmell using a handler on keyup (rarely as useful as keydown of keypress) for an enter key?...to add a hardcoded number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script loads, input is empty. Later, in the function the script is trying to add 6 to NaN, which will give you NaN.

This should work:

```
<script>
     var output = document.getElementById("output");
     var input = document.getElementById("input");


    function addnum(N) {
       var int_input = parseInt(input.value); 
       int_input = int_input + N;
       output.innerHTML = int_input;
    }
    // Your eventListener function can be placed here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in console

```
var input = "12";
var int_input = parseInt(input);

function addnum(N) {
  int_input = int_input + N;
  console.log(int_input);
}
addnum(6);
```

do a console.log() with the input, to see what value it has.